# Get the month name from a timestamp column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to get the month name.

For example: `2020-06-30T00:00:00.000+00:00`

I need to show `June` as output from the above example record from date column

just trying like this

```
select to_char(aia.invoice_date,'Month') from dual
```

but it's showing output as `06` but I need as `June`.

Comment: You mention the column is a date, but from your example it looks like a timestamp. Can you conform exactly how it is defined in the table?

Comment: Your `to_char()` works for both dates and timestamps ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf528fff71eaf0453df5336e4ba3c625)). Can you create a test case to illustrate the issue you are having?